# NSwag Studio - How to remove the StringEnumConverter attribute from the generated enum properties?

Tags: c#, nswagstudio

I'm generating client C# code using NSwag Studio. All my enum properties have this attribute applied:

[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]

Is there a way to NOT have that attribute added to the generated properties?